# Concatenating odd number of bytes and reading as an Int

Tags: javascript

I'm interested in being able to read and write 24-bit wav files. The web audio api + recorderjs seems great for 16-bit wavs, but professional audio is recorded and manipulated at 24-bit usually. I'm wondering if there is a way in javascript to concatenate 3 binary bytes from an array buffer and read them as an int.

**Solution:**

```
var sample = 0;

for (var b = 0; b < bytesPerSample; b++) { 

    sample <<= 8;
    sample |= data[b]; // data is a Uint8Array          

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure:

```
var a = [0xc,0xa,0xb];
a.reduce(function(p,c){return p<<8|c;},0).toString(16) // "c0a0b"
```

Comment: It seems I can't use reduce on array buffers or typed arrays.

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp Are you able to read from them 3 bytes at a time and apply this code?